# React PropTypes.func: Specify function return type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following propTypes:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    getStringFromItem: PropTypes.func,
    getTitleComponentFromItem: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Already from naming, it's obvious that the function supplied to `getStringFromItem` should return a string and the function supplied to `getTitleComponentFromItem` should return a node.

I am not asking for a way to check that all paths of the function return a correctly typed object, but is there a way to specify more details about the expected PropTypes.func?

Comment: Not an answer, which is why I comment: I don't think you can do this with `PropTypes`, but TypeScript makes this easy, e.g. `const MyComponent = (props: { getStringFromItem: () => string; getTitleComponentFromItem: () => JSX.Element; }) => { /* ... */ };`

Comment: Without TypeScript, I don't think it is possible to achieve that as prop-types are a very simple library just to validate prop-typish objects in a simple manner.